# SQL Query to skip row if it has got same datetime interval

Tags: sql-server

can someone help me to achieve my desired result form the following sql query.

```
SELECT
    StartTime , EndTime, max(ClinicID) as ClinicID, max([StartDate]) as StartDate, 
    max([EndDate]) as EndDate, max(SlotLength) as SlotLength, max(Capacity) as Capacity
FROM [Oceano].[dbo].[AmsClinicTemplateSection]
where   ClinicID = 'PY2Q'
and  ( [EndDate] is null or [EndDate] > '2017-12-14')
and  ([StartDate] < '2017-12-14')
group by StartTime, EndTime
```

this query returns the following results:

```
StartTime   EndTime ClinicID    StartDate   EndDate SlotLength  Capacity
1899-12-30 09:00:00.000 1899-12-30 11:20:00.000 PY2Q    2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 NULL    20  1
1899-12-30 09:00:00.000 1899-12-30 11:40:00.000 PY2Q    2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 NULL    20  1
1899-12-30 14:00:00.000 1899-12-30 16:20:00.000 PY2Q    2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 NULL    20  1
```

first two rows has got start and end time from 9.00 to 11.20 and 9.00 to 11.40. I need to keep the second row as its has covered the time of first row as well. can someone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, in the absence of Sample data, however, perhaps:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT StartTime , EndTime,
           MAX(ClinicID) AS ClinicID,
           MAX([StartDate]) AS StartDate, 
           MAX([EndDate]) AS EndDate,
           MAX(SlotLength) AS SlotLength, MAX(Capacity) AS Capacity,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StartTime ORDER BY EndTime DESC) AS RN
    FROM [Oceano].[dbo].[AmsClinicTemplateSection]
    WHERE ClinicID = 'PY2Q'
      AND ([EndDate] IS NULL OR [EndDate] > '2017-12-14')
      AND [StartDate] < '2017-12-14'
    GROUP BY StartTime, EndTime)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If this doesn't work, can you edit your post with some DDL and Consumable Sample Data please, asl well as your expected resultset.

Comment: By applying Group By to StartTime and EndTime columns, it should return only one row per each unique StartTime and EndTime set and there wouldn't be any need to use ROW_NUMBER function. Having the sample data and also DDL would help us figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, but the OP doesn't want a row for every DISTINCT Start and EndTime combination. They want one row per start time, and to display the results for the EndTime that has the highest value. Considering that they haven't, yet, updated their post with the requested DDL and Sample Data, I've used their existing query, which they said got them almost the right results, apart from the "duplicate" row. This *should* work, however, until that DDL and Sample Data is supplied, there's no way to test.

Comment: That is not what I understand from the code: "SELECT StartTime , EndTime, max( ...". Neither from the description itself: "I need to keep the second row as its has covered the time of first row as well."

Comment: @Farzin :group by not gonna work in this scenario as it has same start time but with different end time.

Comment: @Larnu: thanks you solution works like a charm , thats exactly what i needed. thanks a bunch

Comment: @RulezS: May I ask what you didn't simply try "SELECT StartTime , MAX(EndTime) AS EndTime, MAX(ClinicID) AS ClinicID, .. GROUP BY StartTime" ?

Comment: @Farzin: Well this also gonna work fine but previously you have mentioned to group by start and end time both and without using max with end time. By using your last query , it works fine with me and give me the desired results as well.